# On Account field value change, need address values to change also

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction, actionsupport

I have a master detail relation with Account(master) and Address_vod__c (child).
I am showing Account as apex input field. Now on change of Account field , address values also need to changed. Please find below what I have tried.

**Apex Page**

```
 <apex:inputField value="{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Account_abv__c}" required="true"  id="check" />

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputText value="Address"  />

      <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block" id="pwPanel" >
      <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock"/>  
     <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!AddressID}" required="true" >
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!address}" ></apex:selectOptions>
          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="check" action="{!address}" status="Status1"/>
      </apex:selectList>


       <apex:actionStatus id="Status1" >
                        <apex:facet name="start" >
                          <img src="/img/loading.gif" />                    
                        </apex:facet>
                    </apex:actionStatus>
                </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:outputPanel> 
   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

**Apex code**

```
public List<SelectOption> getAddress()
 {  AddID= new Set<ID>();
 act =System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('ABC');
     List<SelectOption> optionaddress = new List<SelectOption>();
     optionaddress.add(new selectoption('none','---Select--'));
     for(Account ac: [Select Id,Name From Account where ID=:Test.Account_abv__c])
     {

       for(Address_vod__c c: [Select Id,Name,Address_line_2_vod__c, City_vod__c , State_vod__c , Zip_vod__c From Address_vod__c where Account_vod__c=:ac.ID ])      
        {  if(c!=null){
             AddID.add(c.ID);
             }

        Address=c.Name+','+c.Address_line_2_vod__c+','+c.City_vod__c+','+c.State_vod__c+','+c.Zip_vod__c;


         optionaddress.add(new SelectOption(c.ID,Address));
        }


     }


     return optionaddress;    


}
```

Comment: What's your problem? I think you need to add an action support with the event "onchange' on the account input field wich calls a method which reload the adresses.

Comment: I have getAccount method where I am preparing the data. Issue is with my above code Address field is always null.

Comment: Where does this variable "Test.Account_abv__c" come from?

Comment: Test is the instance of object in standard controller. Account_abv__c is a field of it. Actually I need to pass the selected Account's ID there but not getting the way to do.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand well what you want to do.

```
public List<SelectOption> getAddress()
 {  AddID= new Set<ID>();
 act =System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('ABC');
     List<SelectOption> optionaddress = new List<SelectOption>();
     optionaddress.add(new selectoption('none','---Select--'));
     for(Account ac: [Select Id From Account where ID=:Form_Requests_abv__c.Account_abv__c])
     {

       for(Address_vod__c c: [Select Id,Name,Address_line_2_vod__c, City_vod__c , State_vod__c , Zip_vod__c From Address_vod__c where Account_vod__c=:ac])      
        {  if(c!=null){
             AddID.add(c.ID);
             }

        Address=c.Name+','+c.Address_line_2_vod__c+','+c.City_vod__c+','+c.State_vod__c+','+c.Zip_vod__c;


         optionaddress.add(new SelectOption(c.ID,Address));
        }


     }


     return optionaddress;    


}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is throwing below error.  Compile Error: Invalid bind expression type of Schema.SObjectField for column of type Id.

Comment: I just edited my code to avoid this error.

Comment: Hi, it's still there , same error.

Comment: What's the code of the row causing the error?

Comment: This is the line.         for(Address_vod__c c: [Select Id,Name,Address_line_2_vod__c, City_vod__c , State_vod__c , Zip_vod__c From Address_vod__c where Account_vod__c=:Form_Requests_abv__c.Account_abv__c.ID ])

Comment: Ok I give it a last try. If it's not working I think I can't help you. I just edited my code.